# Grouping table rows with class suffix/prefix in css/scss

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am making a webbased liveupdating scoreboard for car/karting racing and i need to visually group rows in the scoreboard table together.

[Part of the scoreboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/938Iw.png)

My question is, is it possible to achieve this in pure css/scss using prefix/suffix selectors?

The view is constantly updating and therefor i don't want to make to many computations in the client.

The relevant part of the table markup

```
<tr className={trClassName}>
    <td className="posChange">
        <i className={iconClass} aria-hidden="true" />
     </td>
     <td class="group-{group}" />
     <td className="rnk">
        <div>
            <span>{driver.position}</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The application is written in react and styled with scss

Comment: The answer is: Yes it is

Comment: I am not sure why you are assuming that doing the computation through CSS will be less computationally intensive than doing the grouping through javascript.

Either approach will result in computation being done on the client. The logic for the javascript approach is likely going to be easier to write than the logic for the CSS approach.

Trying to optimize the performance by using CSS seems like premature optimization - write it in JS and see how it works. Likely, it won't be something that needs optimization.

Comment: You can create like three different classes "grouped" "grouped--start" "grouped--end" and then apply the classes based on your application logic. I would assume that you can use some kind of absolutely positioned before element to generate the visuals, although I haven't thought it through.